# Запрос на извлечение последних записей в MySQL

Tags: joomla, php, mysql

Всем привет!

Что-то уже мозги не соображают после рабочего дня. Помогите с запросиком... Есть таблицы `ads_transport`, `ads_estate`, `ads_buysell`. Задача - вытянуть последние записи. Структура таблиц разная, сортировать нужно по дате DESC. Всем заранее спасибо.

**Добавлено.**

[[@Ozim](/users/2690/ozim)](/users/2690/ozim), вот это уже ближе к истине! Вот структура одной из таблиц

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jos_ads_buysell (
  id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  type varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  category varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  price varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  info text NOT NULL, contacts varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  phone varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  views int(11) NOT NULL,
  created_date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  hash varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

Comment: осталось определить, до какого момента записи считать последними..

Answer (score 1):

Все решилось с помощью нескольких запросов через UNION

Если комуто нужно допустим вот так

select data,id,time,'' as category, '' as descr form tbl1 
UNION select '' as data, id, time,category, descr form tbl2 ORDER BY time DESC

где поля data,id,time в первой тоблице
id,time,descrt,category поля второй таблицы

может както корявенько но запрос очень быстрый и решил полностью мои нужды !
Просьба к модерам если посчитаете нужным перенесите в ответы из комментов

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table_name 
where rownum<10 
order by date desc
```

Comment: К сожалению меня неправильно поняли:( Мне нужно как бы объединить все таблицы в одну и вытянуть все поля, сортируя по дате.

Comment: Не видя полей таблиц, трудно предположить что Вам на самом деле нужно. 

Неужели декартово произведение 3-х таблиц?